# How to group a resultset by day?

Tags: sql-server-2005, query

I have a table with a LastUpdated field that is DateTime and wanted to know how can I group months of data collected by chronological days such that I can derive the number of records in each day going back 3 months?

I am using `datediff` but it would be great if I can have a field with the actual date and a count in the resultset.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(),crDate), COUNT(*)
FROM tracexml
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(d,crDate, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Does this fall under too basic? Does this belong on SO?

Comment: @jcolebrand do you have an answer or not?

Comment: yes, and so does Google. I just want to contribute to the site being a little more like what has been discussed on Meta, and a little less "plz gimme teh codez"

Answer (score 2):

For starters, why are you reversing your fields in the datediff?

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(),crDate), COUNT(*)
FROM tracexml
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(d,crDate, GETDATE())
```

Number two, why does this not work for you?

```
SELECT crDate, COUNT(*)
FROM tracexml
GROUP BY crDate
```

Comment: Also note: I smell a revised set of requirements coming on that makes this query actually answerable the way that he wants it answered.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following. I even added a few extra columns if you wanted to put it into a nifty little pivot table where you could group by year, month, day

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),crDate,120) as [crDate]
    ,datePart(yy,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),crDate,120) )  as [crYear]
    ,datePart(mm,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),crDate,120) )  as [crMonth]
    ,datePart(dd,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),crDate,120) )  as [crDay]
    , COUNT(*) as [traceCount]
FROM tracexml
WHERE crDate > dateAdd(d,-30,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getDate(),120))
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),crDate,120)
    ,datePart(yy,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),crDate,120) )  
    ,datePart(mm,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),crDate,120) )  
    ,datePart(dd,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),crDate,120) )
```